# Yeoman can't find generators

Tags: windows, node.js, npm, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I have installed yeoman npm install -g yo 
and a controller etc. npm install -g generator-meanjs

I get this error :

> You don't seem to have a generator with the name meanjs installed.
>   You can see available generators with npm search yeoman-generator and then insta
>   ll them with npm install [name].
>   To see the 0 registered generators run yo with the `--help` option.

and running yo in cmd (I'm on windows) also returns 0 generators, only menu to install.

What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must to re-install your nodejs with the latest version.

add environments variables to path

```
NODE_PATH = C:\Program Files\nodejs;
npm root= C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules;
```

and it will work .